# Trying to convert a column in a CSV file to text and then export as a .XLSX file - the last 3 numbers of the column are populating as 0's

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlsx, xlwings

I am trying to import a .csv file from a file path and convert the D column to text format so it displays all 20 numbers but it is not exporting correctly. (Ex: 00106829131569064007 but it is exporting to .xlsx as 00106829131569064000)

My code is shown below (I changed some of the file path for privacy reasons)

```
import xlwings as xw

# Import the CSV file
csv_file = r'C:\Users\#######\OneDrive - ########\Desktop\DIQ Morning Report\DIQ Prod Inv\DIQ_Prod_Inv.csv'
wb = xw.Book(csv_file, delimiter='')

# Change column D format to text
wb.sheets[0].range('D:D').column_format = 'TEXT'

# Set column D to show 20 numerical characters without scientific notation
wb.sheets[0].range('D:D').number_format = '0000000000000000'

# Export the data to an Excel file
excel_file = r'C:\Users\#######.#######\OneDrive - #######.com\Desktop\DIQ Morning Report\DIQ Prod Inv\DIQ_Prod_Inv_1.xlsx'
wb.save(excel_file)
```

I know that I can just open the csv file in excel and transform the data type in column D from whole number to text and then load it into the excel file. I am trying to do this through python.

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks

I tried to use python (xlwings package) to import a csv file and change a column to text format. After running my code, the .xlsx file opens and the column replaces the last 3 digits to zeros.

I expected it to give me 20 digits that were accurate to the original data that I pulled from a database.

Comment: This `number_format = '0000000000000000'` has 16 digits not 20.